# a variable is not taken

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my code and i don't understand why this variable "q" is not taken

```js
  $(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
                // we don't want to do anything if we aren't resizing.
                if (!isResizing)
                    return;
                var k = $('#' + base[0].id + '_start').val()

                p = parseInt(e.clientX - base.offset().left)
                q = ((p / screenarea) * pixalvalue);
               
               
                $('#' + base[0].id + '_value').val(q+k );

                base.css('width', p);
```

if i remove this code the other functions are worked but i want that var q calculation.

```js
 
                q = ((p / screenarea) * pixalvalue);
```

Blockquote

Comment: what are the values of screenarea and pixalvalue?

Comment: What exactly is the outcom? An error message? q=0?  `screenarea` sounds like it could be a big number (wherever it comes from) and big number divisions on int might end up 0.

Comment: don't you need to declare it as variable first ??? var q = ((p / screenarea) * pixalvalue); or at least put coma after declaring k ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing comas when declaring your variables ...

```
var k = $('#' + base[0].id + '_start').val(),
    p = parseInt(e.clientX - base.offset().left),
    q = ((p / screenarea) * pixalvalue);
```

or

```
var k = $('#' + base[0].id + '_start').val();
var p = parseInt(e.clientX - base.offset().left);
var q = ((p / screenarea) * pixalvalue);
```